# How to create object of the class using active record field?

Tags: php, yii2

I've got a simple model with only 2 parameters - 'sum' and 'name'. I created a new object of this model's class and sent it to a view. In view I have two fields - also 'sum' and 'name'. 
When I input values in fields (f.e. sum=10, name=Joe) I expect that my current sum will decrease by 10 but for user Joe it will increase by 10. (There are three columns also in database - 'id', 'sum' and 'name').
But I can't transfer this name from field to update db.

```
//Controller
public function actionSum()
{
    $model = new SumForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($user = $model->sumfunction()) {
        } return $this->goHome();
    }
    return $this->render('sum', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

//Model
class SumForm extends Model
{
public $sum;
public $name;


public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'sum' => 'Sum',
        'name' => 'Name',
    ];
}

public function sumfunction()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $desc = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->getId());
        $desc->sum -= $this->sum;
        $desc->save();
        $inc = User::findOne(['name'=>Yii::$app->request->post('name')]);
        //here I need to take a row for user which name I input
        $inc->sum += $this->sum;
        $inc->save();
    }
}

//in view 'sum' only two fields and button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use ActiveRecord, you get the parameters attached to the model. In this case, SumForm[name]

Best way for using it:

```
  $inc = User::findOne(['name' => $this->name]);
  $inc->sum += $this->sum;
  $inc->save(false); //without validation! Fix it later.
```

and add in SumForm:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name'], 'string'],
        [['sum'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

and show your User model. There must also be a validators for attributes name and sum.

and in actionSum() change:

```
// if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
```

If the model fails validation, you will see errors in the form.

form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'sum')->textInput() ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('confirm') ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! But there is no update of db in this case.

Comment: Thanks to onmotion for helping. Everything was alright. Only needed post($this->username) instead of post('username').